# Read matrix form txt file into an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a .txt file with a matrix, like this:

0 2 3

4 1 6

0 3 4

The numbers can be separated by commas or spaces.
I need to load the txt file into a 2D array in JavaScript. I am really new in this language and don't know how to read files element by element.

Comment: Look at the documentation for NodeJS's `fs` (filesystem) built-in package. That should tell you what you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file is stored server side you can use this function to read the contents:

```
function readSingleFile(evt) {
    //Retrieve the first (and only!) File from the FileList object
    var f = evt.target.files[0]; 
  if(f){
    var r = new FileReader();
      r.onload = function(e) { 
       var contents = e.target.result;
       }
    }
}
```

from there it kind of depends on your expected output how you parse the contents but hopefully this gets you moving.

Answer (score 0):

Following the answer from @rubynewbie, wanted to add a slightly different slant. Assuming running a node server and again, loading the file locally...

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var content = fs.readFileSync('/path/to/file');

// Split on linefeeds to get rows
var row_list = content.split('\n');

// Split rows into cells
var matrix = row_list.map((r) => r.split(/ +/));
```

(Typed on phone, so probably fairly buggy.)